# Is there an idiom that roughly means "we gotta do what we gotta do"?

Tags: idiom-request

Is there an idiom that roughly means "we gotta do what we gotta do"? I can think of another one like "I gotta earn my keep", but it's a little too specific and wage related. Is there any general idiom that means roughly the same thing? I can't think of one.

I am looking for a general idiom that can be used in almost any context and not just some random phrase.

Comment: I tried to answer but I don't think I fully understand the question. Can you say more about the meaning you're trying to capture?

There are numerous terms that have a literal meaning and that can be used to mean something more indirect or symbolic:

 - (I've got to) pay the rent (said when buying a coffee at Starbucks, because staying there without buying something would feel like freeloading)
 - (I've got) mouths to feed (i.e. I have obligations)

Comment: "You gotta do what you gotta do" is pretty standard.

Comment: required, necessary, unavoidable, crucial, imperative, urgent, vital, binding, compulsory, obligatory

Comment: What is so wrong with "you gotta do what you gotta do" that you are looking for an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Your original suggestion is fine:

> Do what you gotta do

but the word "**gotta**" is only used in informal, spoken English.

Try

> Do what **you have to do**

[*Google N-grams*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=what+you+have+to+do%2C+what+you+gotta+do&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhat%20you%20have%20to%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhat%20you%20gotta%20do%3B%2Cc0) shows that this formation has become incredibly popular since 1970.  It is very well understood.

If you feel the original sentence is not clear, or too informal, you can try:

> We will do what **has to be done.**

### Or use a single word

User [Sam](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/32404/sam) suggests words that provide this meaning:

> required, necessary, unavoidable, crucial, imperative, urgent, vital, binding, compulsory, obligatory

These have different levels of formality.  In spoken English the word "urgent" is fine, while the words "compulsory" and "obligatory" suggest *formal rules*.

Answer (score 2):

"I gotta do what I gotta do" *is* an idiom. It is widely known and understood to mean you are compelled to do something, either because you *have* to or because you *want* to. It can also suggest a means to an end that you don't particularly like, but need the outcome.

Variations of this include "I have to do what I have to do", and "I do what I must". These are not "formal" as such, but are more grammatically correct than the slang "gotta".